# Amplifying DC signal via BJT

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, bjt, signal

I am using LED as a light sensor, the range of output is from 0-700mV DC, I want to amplify/scale this signal to 0-3.3V DC.

My question is, what is the best way to scale the output signal to the desired range using only BJTs?

The constraint of using only BJTs is because of lock-down due to Corona Virus pandemic, I cannot go and buy something like an opamp.

Comment: Aren't you able to order components and get them shipped to you?

Comment: No, in india it is solid curfew/marshal law kind of lockdown

Answer (score 2):

The trick that isn't mentioned yet is that your LED may show you 700mV with your voltmeter, but that's because your voltmeter is a crazy high input impedance (like 10Meg probably).  The LED can't source much current - Maybe nano-to-microamps at best.  In other words, it has a very high output impedance.  If attached to a load much smaller (say, the 10k base resistor of a BJT amplifier) is not going to have the current drive needed.  Your 0-700mV signal will disappear.  BJT's are current-devices, not voltage.  This would be way easier if you had MOSFETs handy, because those ARE voltage controlled (nearly infinite input impedance).  But you don't - You have BJT's - so you gotta deal with currents instead of voltages.

TO simulate the LED, a 0-700mV-0 variable voltage source and a 10MEG resistor are connected to the base of the first transistor.  This resistor is NOT part of the circuit you'd build!!!!    It represents the output impedance of the LED.   (i.e. your LED is simulated by the voltage source AND the 10Meg resistor)  I don't know what the impedance actually is, but it's gotta be in the 1-10M range at least.  Note you DO need the 100k resistor here.

Since all you have are BJTs, the first stage should be a voltage follower.  LIke your voltmeter, and like a good JFET OPAMP, this circuit has a high input impedance, so it'll buffer the LED current.  You don't get voltage gain here - You get current gain.  That'll let us drive the next stage.

The rest of the circuit is simple, just a couple typical common emitter amplifiers.  The diode in stage 1 lifts the output high enough to forward bias the base of stage 2.

Three pics.  First two are the circuit.  One clean one so you can read it easily, the second shows all the initial bias voltages & currents  (this is when LED current = 0) to help your understanding and troubleshooting.

Third pic is plot of voltages. Note the blue trace showing LED action.  It shows the LED source going from 0V->0.7V->0V, but you see it as 3.3V->2.6V->3.3V.   DOn't be fooled by that. It's VCC referenced, not GND referenced, so you see the voltage as a subtraction...

Each trace is plotted at locations shown by arrows in the first pic.   The yellow trace is the output of the last transistor - This is what you're interested in.  You'll note my voltage rail is 3.3V, and that the output nearly goes the full requested 0-3.3V  (Not quite, but hey - You're not paying me here  ;) Seriously, it would be very very difficult to achieve True rail-to-rail - You're not getting that with a practical discrete transistor circuit -

This won't work exactly as is because it'll be dependent on each transistors Beta, but you can definitely tweak it.   Build it a stage at a time, and reference the voltages shown.  Tweak resistors to get those points to closely match.

[image: Email me if you can't see the image]

Answer (score 1):

While it would invert the direction, 0 = ~ 3.3V and 0.7 = ~ 0V, you can make it with an NPN and some resistors, alternatively you could make it a 2 stage amplifier of this type if the direction needs to be maintained,

[image]

[Falstad Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%200.016668213447794653%2050%205%2043%0At%20992%20144%201040%20144%200%201%20-1.454428306316874%200.5478802833643115%20100%0Ar%20992%20144%20992%2016%200%20819999.9999999999%0Ar%20992%20144%20864%20144%200%20150000%0AR%20864%20144%20784%20144%200%201%20400%200.35000000000000003%200.35000000000000003%200%200.5%0Ag%201040%20160%201040%20176%200%0AR%20992%2016%20992%200%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Ar%201040%20128%201040%2016%200%208200%0Aw%201040%2016%20992%2016%200%0AO%201040%20128%201168%20128%201%0Ao%208%208%200%2012290%203.164737941811079%200.0001%200%201%0A)

Answer (score 1):

Since the current produced is VERY low, what I can think of at the moment is using a darlington amplifier with another transistor as an inverter (or DC level shifter).
Kind of like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBYegt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that this is just a preliminary schematic. I haven't done detailed analysis or calculations, just some quick figures in my head.
More precise suggestions are welcome.
Basically, the R1 should be adjusted for a 0V output with no voltage generated by the LED;  in other words, short out the LED while adjusting it. It would be a good idea to use trimmer instead, maybe about 10k maximum resistance.
The R3 should be adjusted for the amount of gain you need, to get the desired voltage range at the output.
Supply voltage should probably be from 5V to 10V, but definitely regulated/stable.
Diodes D1 and D2 can be replaced with 2 transistors to match the Vbe voltage drop better.

Like I said, if someone knows better, feel free to suggest improvements, but nothing too complex. Simplicity is the key here.

Answer (score 1):

A voltage-output photodiode is operating in photovoltaic mode, which
may not be optimal.   To produce voltage gain without sensitivity
to ambient temperature requires a two-transistor amplifier; this
should do it (but the output is not ground-referenced).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7uDok.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>